# How to make a Vector2 Direction to became a Vector3 Direction along Binormal or whatever it calls?

Tags: unity-game-engine, math, vector

Currently i have a 2D Vector2 `Direction`, if i cast it to `(Vector3)Direction`,
it would be a direction vector rotate alone `V3.forward` if i am not wrong right?

I've already successfully got all 3 vectors, green is the normal, red is the tangent of the curved, blue is just the binormal.
What i want is making the 2D Vector2 Direction rotate along blue and start from red in world space.

I would like to know both unity function base solution and the additionally pure math base solution if anyone can help.

[image]
[image]

Comment: It is a vector that rotates along forward **starting from right**, so you need at least 2 vectors to form a plane for the vector2 to rotate on.

Comment: I've already successfully got all 3 vectors, green is the normal, red is the tangent of the curved, blue is just the binormal.
What i want is making the 2D Vector2 Direction rotate along blue and start from red.

Comment: I still don't really get the question tbh. I understand you have the green `up` vector and you know the red `right` vector ... and you seem to also know the blue `forward` vector (probably simply cross product of up and right) ... all three are 3D vectors ... so what exactly are you looking for? How is the cyan vector determined? what does the angle depend on?

Comment: The cyan `2D dir` in the picture is a vector2 from the game screen center to my mouse screen position, i want to get the world space vector3 direction which the direction is the `2D dir` rotate along blue axis and start from red(according to what @shingo describe ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to my understanding what you get is a `Vector2 direction`.

Now you want to convert it into a `Vector3` but align it with a coordinate system composed of the known `up` and `right` vectors.

So what you want to do is basically take the `right` vector and rotate it around the `forward` vector by the given angle.

So I would first get that angle

```
var angle = Vector2.SignedAngle(Vector2.right, direction);
```

Then get the forward axis we want to rotate around

```
var forward = Vector3.Cross(right, up);
```

Calculate the rotation to be applied

```
var rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, forward);
```

and finally apply that rotation to the existing `right` vector

```
var result = rotation * right;
```

Comment: Huge! It work perfectly first of all! I can finally have my debug arrow works!
But secondly, it work too perfect that i don't understand how Quaternion work with Vector. Or maybe i just have 0 sense about Quaternion.

Comment: `result` is normalized, you forgot to multiply it by the length.

Comment: Is fine, since it's just a direction. Thx for mention that.

Comment: @SoMuchSMx you were speaking of a direction so I didn't think the length matters ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are many solutions in Unity to your problem. In mathematics, it can actually be summarized as [how to find the rotation matrix from the original coordinate system to a rotated coordinate system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34391968/how-to-find-the-rotation-matrix-between-two-coordinate-systems)(red, green, blue). The link points to another SO question, according to that this is a simple matrix operation:

```
var mx = new Matrix4x4(red, green, blue, new Vector4(0, 0, 0, 1));
var dir = mx.MultiplyVector(direction);
```

Comment: Wow, can't even think of that, it's so far ahead form what i know.
Is this more efficient in performance? I know nothing about Matrix and if it is, i would like trying to figure it out. Tho I think @derHugo's solution is more math idiot friendly lol, maybe it's a nice entry to get in to this i think?

Comment: And this work extremely well too. All can i did is just normalize it.

Comment: @SoMuchSMx this is way more efficient than my solution! ;) In most cases you can assume that any matrix based operation will be way less performance intense. Whether it is easier to maintain is up to you but I would go with this one